# Haskell. Return a list of numbers in which at least one of the same digits is present as in "n"

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, type-mismatch

Given a list of numbers "`lst`" and the number "`n`". Return a list of numbers in which at least one of the same digits is present as in "`n`". The number system is considered decimal.

The function should return the following results:

```
sameDigits [1,11,45,23] 12 -> [1,11,23]
sameDigits [72,47,55] 7 -> [72, 47]
```

I solve the problem using "list comprehension". I iterate over the numbers from the list, convert them to a "string of elements" and get for each element a "list of different sets" of these elements, and compare them with a list of different sets obtained from a given number. If the length of the list is `> 0`, then I include this item in the list of results. I solve the problem using the function "`subsequences`", which returns all possible iterations of each element of the list; and the functions "intersect", which returns list of common elements for two lists:

```
 let sameDigits lst n = [ x | x <- lst, if length (tail 
        (subsequences (show x)
          `intersect` subsequences (show n))) > 0 
     then x else [] ]
```

But the function crashes with an error, help me fix it.

```
<interactive>:63:131: 
Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ 
         with actual type ‘[t0]’ 
In the expression: [] 
In the expression: 
    if length (tail (subsequences (show x) 
         `intersect` subsequences (show n))) > 0 
      then x else [] 
 In a stmt of a list comprehension: 
    if length (tail (subsequences (show x) 
         `intersect` subsequences (show n))) > 0 
      then x else []
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: <interactive>:63:131:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type ‘[t0]’
    In the expression: []
    In the expression:
      if length
           (tail (subsequences (show x) `intersect` subsequences (show n)))
         > 0 then
          x
      else
          []
    In a stmt of a list comprehension:
      if length
           (tail (subsequences (show x) `intersect` subsequences (show n)))
         > 0 then
          x
      else
          []

Comment: All clauses after the pipe in a comprehension should be Boolean expressions (a predicate involving `x` in this case), so you don't need to make it into an `if` expression.

Comment: Exactly !!!! Thank you very much, everything turned out !!

Comment: `length x > 0` is better expressed as `not (null x)`, and `length (tail x) > 0`  as `not (null (drop 1 x))`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Robin Zigmond! Here is a function built on his recommendation.

```
let sameDigits lst n = [ x | x <- lst, length (tail (subsequences (show x) `intersect` subsequences (show n))) > 0 ]

sameDigits [1,11,45,23] 12
-> [1,11,23]
sameDigits [72,47,55] 7
-> [72,47]
```